# Send Attachments in mail using java

Tags: java, email

I am able to send and email in Java and attaching files using the MimeBodyPart. The attachments Which I sent are being converted to email body and the content in the files is being displayed in the body. Is there any mistake in my code below which is converting the attachment to body?

//http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java

```
package axisSharePoint;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class EmailAttachmentSender {

    public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String host, String port,
            final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
            String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles)
            throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        //properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        //properties.put("mail.user", userName);
        //properties.put("mail.password", password);

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };
        //Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // creates message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

        // creates multi-part
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // adds attachments
        if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
            for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
                MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                System.out.println(filePath);

                //DataSource  source = new FileDataSource(new 
                                           File(filePath));
                //attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                //attachPart.setFileName(filePath);
                try {
                    attachPart.attachFile(new File(filePath));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            }
        }
        // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
        msg.setContent(multipart);


        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Test sending e-mail with attachments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // SMTP info
        String host = "*******";
        String port = "25";
        String mailFrom = "*********";
        String password = "";

        // message info
        String mailTo = "*****";
        String subject = "New email with attachments";
        String message = "I have some attachments for you.";

        // attachments
        String[] attachFiles = new String[1];

        attachFiles[0]="SampleFile1.txt";

        try {
            sendEmailWithAttachments(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo,
                subject, message, attachFiles);
            System.out.println("Email sent.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not send email.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Received the output in the following format:

```
------=_Part_0_363771819.1499875061651
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

I have some attachments for you.
------=_Part_0_363771819.1499875061651
Content-Type: text/plain; name=SampleFile1.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SampleFile1.txt

This is External File
------=_Part_0_363771819.1499875061651--
```

Comment: If you can look at the source of the message that was received, look into the mime parts and make sure that they have a `Content-Disposition` of "attachment". If so, then it's the mail client's fault.

Comment: Hi RealSkeptic. Sure, will check and update here! Thanks

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel: Thanks for your suggestion! I updated the post with the output.